# Annoying blank line in Idle shell

Tags: python

I noticed that when i run my program the IDLE shell writes a blank line in between my prints. I am adding a screenshot so you guys know what exactly i think. The blank line is not written in my program, it just happens automatically, is there any way to turn off these blank lines?

[blank lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48CTY.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the actual prints. Also, please write the output *as text* to the question as well. Both should be rendered fine when using code formatting.

Comment: please include input as well as output of your codes.

Comment: that's not a feature of idle, it must be something in your code, you're probably printing strings that already include a linebreak.

Comment: it's default python idle printing format

Comment: @Leanardo There is no IDLE printing format.  IDLE displays what Python sends in response to user code.  For example, `for i in range(4): print(i)` prints 0 to 3 on separate lines with no intervening blank lines.  Without the code, the question in incomplete and it is impossible to explain the result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re getting a new line added after the print. Try adding a .rstrip() to the variable inside print. Without seeing the input code, it may be hard to determine what is going on. This would be my guess though. Something like this should work:

```py
print(test.rstrip())
```